# Teklaopenapi interface with Python

Tags: python

I have installed the relevant packages for the API using Nuget in Visual Studio. What I cannot seem to get guidance on is how to add references for use in a Python script? Using the references that are created in the Visual Studio project as import statements in the Python script does not work. Cannot find any guidance on this online or on the Tekla API page.

Tried using the references as import statements but they do not work.

Comment: does this help? https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/documentation/model-code-examples

Comment: The NuGet package [TeklaOpenApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TeklaOpenAPI/) is for .NET not for Python.